# separate a string array to several small arrays

Tags: c#

how can I separate an array in smaller arrays?

```
string[] str = new string[145]
```

I want two arrays for this; like

```
string[] str1 = new string[99];
string[] str2 = new string[46];
```

how can I do this from the source of str?

1- Then I want to put together the arrays into List all together but there is only add item? no add items? or any other way to make the  string[145] array again..

Comment: the most simple solution would be to use foreach ( ) or for ( ) or do you want to use LINQ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) to get some of the items from the source array to another array.

```
string[] str1 = new string[99];
string[] str2 = new string[46];
Array.Copy(str, 0, str1, 0, 99);
Array.Copy(str, 99, str2, 0, 46);
```

You can use the same to copy them back.

Comment: It is the answer since we don't The LINQ  over here.

Answer (score 10):

Simplest way, using LINQ:

```
string[] str1 = str.Take(99).ToArray();
string[] str2 = str.Skip(99).ToArray();
```

Putting them back together:

```
str = str1.Concat(str2).ToArray();
```

These won't be hugely efficient, but they're extremely simple :) If you need more efficiency, [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx) is probably the way to go... but it would take a *little* bit more effort to get right.

Comment: nice didn't thought of that :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a list, use the `List<T>.AddRange` method:

```
var array = new string[145];
var list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(array);
```

Comment: note this answers only the 2nd question. Not the first one about seperating the array into 2 smaller arrays

Comment: @PoweRoy: That's because the first part had already been answered!